# Same Random Data generated when .RData is loaded

Tags: r

When a .RData file is loaded same random numbers are generated everytime. For example try this: (Type these in terminal)

```
rm(list=ls())
x=10 #Just some random value 
save.image("samplefile.RData")

Now try this:
rm(list=ls())
load("samplefile.RData")
print(runif(n=100,min=0,max=100)) #Now it prints same random numbers everytime i run above code junket.

Can anyone please explain?

Thanks.
```

Comment: Try ls(all = TRUE)

Comment: @RichScriven If you are launching R from an `.RData` file, try this. In one session, do `rnorm(1)` and then `q("yes")`. Now launch R from that `.RData` file, and do `rnorm(4)`. Launch it again and do `rnorm(4)`, and you'll see what the OP is asking about. (After this experiment, to clean up and then save the cleaned up image without the saved random seed, do `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)); q("yes")` .)

Comment: Thanks @JoshO'Brien - I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to load a .RData file that has a saved .Random.seed, you can reset the seed using the clock time and this bit of code:

```
a <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
set.seed(a)
```

Note that there are benefits to being able to exactly reproduce randomizations, i.e., reproducible research. But for everyday purposes it's probably safer to save and load objects rather than the environment. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/readRDS

Answer (score 2):

This is intentional behaviour - .Random.seed is saved within Rdata file. If you want different data generated just rm() the value before that or set it to a different one.

Comment: Do you know where exactly or how it is stored? If I do `rm(.Random.seed)` before `save.image` and then load the image, `.Random.seed` is there again